# Can't put custom parameters to Firebase Dynamic links

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I need to put custom `query` params to firebase `dynamic link` leading to AppStore. Once a user has installed the app I need to get that URL with query params.

**I tried to build both short and long dynamic links, but it doesn't work.**

Firebase dynamic link configuration for https://myApp.page.link/ios:
[image]

**Things I've tried:**

```
1) https://myApp.page.link/ios/?link=https://apps.apple.com/ru/app...&ifl=https://www.google.com&gclid=4324234

2) https://myApp.page.link/?link=https://apps.apple.com/ru/app...&gclid=4324234

3) https://myApp.page.link/?link=https://apps.apple.com/ru/app...?gclid=4324234

4) https://myApp.page.link/?link=https://apps.apple.com/ru/app...&ifl=https://www.google.com&gclid=4324234
```

Inside the app I try to get the initial link using flutter firebase_dynamic_links pub package and i always get only link, leading to AppStore with no query params.

What am I doing wrong? How should links look like to be able to put custom param into app?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the parameters of your deep link are URL Encoded.
For example, if your deep link look like this:

```
https://example.com/login?token=GDGEGDFGE345DF
```

Then your long dynamic link should look something like this:

```
https://example.page.link/?link=https://example.com/login?token%3DGDGEGDFGE345DF&apn=com.my.app.package&ibi=com.my.app.bundle
```

As you can see the `token=` parameter becomes `token%3D`, the `=` sign is encoded.
Otherwise, `firebase_dynamic_links` cannot parse your deep link correctly and you may not get any query parameters back.

Comment: You probably also need to URL encode the entire value assigned to your `link` param: `https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Flogin%3Ftoken%3DGDGEGDFGE345DF`

Comment: Did this solution work for you @alectogeek ?